# Wireshark capture showing a TCP packet with no flags

Tags: tcp, wireshark, packet-analysis

In our network, I captured a TCP packet by Wireshark that has no flag set.

What is the meaning of such packet ? Here is the dissection in text format :

```
Frame 1: 54 bytes on wire (432 bits), 54 bytes captured (432 bits)
Ethernet II, Src: ***, Dst: ***
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: ***, Dst: ***
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 20, Dst Port: 80, Seq: 0, Len: 0
    Source Port: 20
    Destination Port: 80
    [Stream index: 0]
    [TCP Segment Len: 0]
    Sequence Number: 0
    [Next Sequence Number: 0]
    Acknowledgment Number: 0
    Acknowledgment number (raw): 0
    0101 .... = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
    Flags: 0x000 (<None>)
        000. .... .... = Reserved: Not set
        ...0 .... .... = Accurate ECN: Not set
        .... 0... .... = Congestion Window Reduced: Not set
        .... .0.. .... = ECN-Echo: Not set
        .... ..0. .... = Urgent: Not set
        .... ...0 .... = Acknowledgment: Not set
        .... .... 0... = Push: Not set
        .... .... .0.. = Reset: Not set
        .... .... ..0. = Syn: Not set
        .... .... ...0 = Fin: Not set
        [TCP Flags: ············]
    Window: 8192
    [Calculated window size: 8192]
    [Window size scaling factor: 1 (missing - taken from preference)]
    Checksum: 0xa18c [unverified]
    [Checksum Status: Unverified]
    Urgent Pointer: 0
    [Timestamps]
    [SEQ/ACK analysis]
```

Comment: please post sample data as well. It will help to answer your question

Comment: "_What's that mean?_" and "_due to NDA I can't_" are really two things that do not work together well here. Unfortunately, your question is too broad to answer. We would need specifics.

Comment: We need enough information to answer the question. Generally we need full configurations, but public addresses and passwords should be obfuscated. You can refer to the [Network Engineering Question Checklist](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292/8499) for guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A TCP flag is used in a packet to identify a connection state or provide further information to the receiving party, common examples include SYN, ACK, RST, FIN + more.

In your instance, you've come across a TCP packet without a proper flag set or a malformed flag set.

As for the cause, without knowing your environment I'd hesitate to comment. I'd start by capturing the source of the packet and investigating the machine/device for network anomalies.

Comment: it seems odd, I wonder maybe it should be a kind of new attack but I investigate further, Thanks.